# How can I use JVM Client Mode on x64 operating system?

Tags: java, jvm, x86, 64-bit

I need to run the Oracle JVM in the "client mode". Is there any option to do this on an x64 operating system?

I installed Oracle 7 JDK per apt-get. It installed the Oracle JDK and JRE x64 edition. So i have only /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server directory and no amd64/client directory.

On the Oracle website, you can download the JRE Linux x64 and x86 packages, precompiled. I download them both and looked into the folders.

x64 package contains only amd64/server directory.
x86 package contains i386/server AND i386/client directories.

So, what can I do to use the client mode? Have I install the x86 edition of java? I think I can do this only manually and not with apt-get because it recognize that I have a x64 operating system.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to use the client version for?  This has been optimised for applets, in which case the 32-bit version should be fine.

Comment: I've found that as a developer with a laptop having x64 win7, 8 gig of ram, and the 64bit version of the jdk installed... the jvm that gets launched for everything (eclipse, intellij, etc) runs in server mode. What's wrong with that? Server mode doesn't play "nice". It consumes all resources and the whole of the windows UI stutters as it starts up. It would be "nice" if there was a way to specify "-client" for just this purpose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK the 64bit version of the Oracle JVM only supports the server mode at the moment (my guess is we'll never see a client version). [This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_compilers) FAQ would see to support that. I don't think the Open JDK project has a 64bit client version either but it's been a while since I checked: [this](http://openjdk.5641.n7.nabble.com/Client-VM-for-64-bit-linux-td110056.html#a110134) post confirms my suspicion. It seems the server VM is as good as or better than any dedicated client VM would be.

Comment: That specific version of the FAQ also states that there is no support for 64 bit web start: this has however changed since 6u12 (!) - 

    64-Bit Browser Support for Java Plugin and Java Webstart This release supports the New Java Plugin and Java Webstart on AMD64 architecture, on Windows platforms. A Java offline installer (JRE and JDK) is provided. Note, if you use 32-bit and 64-bit browsers interchangeably, you will need to install both 32-bit and 64-bit JREs in order to have Java Plug-In for both browsers. Note that I'm not disputing your answer regarding the outcome :)